# perl passing hash reference not behaving as expected

Tags: perl, hash, reference, pass-by-reference

(**NOTE: I sort of figured this out, see all the way at the end**)

It's kind of late and I've been staring at this code for far too long. I finally wrote a short test program to test hashes and passing them by reference and it is not behaving as I expect. I'm sure there is something very simple I'm missing ... can anyone spot it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();
print "BEFORE ADDING KEYS\n";
print Dumper (\%hash);
test (\%hash, 10);
print "AFTER ADDING KEYS\n";
print Dumper (\%hash);

sub test {

 my %hash = %{$_[0]};
 my $number = $_[1];
 if ($number == 0) { return; }

 print "BEFORE ADDING KEY HASH_REF=$_[0] NUMBER=$number\n";
 print Dumper (\%hash);
 $hash{$number} = $number;
 print "AFTER ADDING KEY\n";
 print Dumper (\%hash);    
 test ($_[0], $number - 1);
}
```

I expect this code to add the numbers 10 to 1 into my hash, but instead the hash gets wiped out and doesn't contain anything once the test routine finishes recursing. What am I missing? Here is the output:

```
BEFORE ADDING KEYS
$VAR1 = {};
BEFORE ADDING KEY HASH_REF=HASH(0xdb82fd0) NUMBER=10
$VAR1 = {};
AFTER ADDING KEY
$VAR1 = {
          '10' => 10
        };
BEFORE ADDING KEY HASH_REF=HASH(0xdb82fd0) NUMBER=9
$VAR1 = {};
AFTER ADDING KEY
$VAR1 = {
          '9' => 9
        };

...

BEFORE ADDING KEY HASH_REF=HASH(0xdb82fd0) NUMBER=1
$VAR1 = {};
AFTER ADDING KEY
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 1
        };
AFTER ADDING KEYS
$VAR1 = {};
```

**Changing this line:**

```
$hash{$number} = $number;
```

to:

```
$_[0]->{$number} = $number;
```

made everything work as expected. Why does the first statement modify a fresh local %hash when I would expect this local %hash to be pointing to the same de-referenced hash reference I originally passed into the routine?

Comment: Re "*Why does the first statement modify a fresh local %hash*", When you have two variables with the same name, only the inner one is visible. Changing `%hash` will therefore change the local one, not the global one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything works as intended. You first statement in the test sub makes a copy of passed hash:

```
 my %hash = %{$_[0]};
```

To mutate passed hash, you should work with hashref, like:

```
 my $hashref= $_[0];

 $hashref->{key} = 'val';
```

This approach will change original hash, not it's copy.

Comment: It was a little intuitive to me that assigning a %hash to a dereferenced hash reference makes a copy!

Comment: Sorry I meant UN-intuitive.